# Converting a java (JAR) application to a windows exe

Tags: java, exec

I have java application with several main methods. I would like to convert it to a windows .exe that does not require a java run time environment. Which application can I use to do so that will convert the application together with its database to exe?. I am currently using excelsior jet. However it can only convert the application to exe leaving the database to interact it wit it externally. Any Advice?

Comment: Check launch4j, I am not sure about embedding database though its good enough than excelsior jet